# Magento 2 - how to disable shipment creation using Event sales_order_shipment_save_before

Tags: magento2

I want to check if the products which are getting shipped are available in my warehouse and if these aren't available then i need to stop the further execution of shipment creation n throw an error message.

I am using "sales_order_shipment_save_before" event observer.

Please let me know what my execution function should return inorder to stop the shipment being created.

```
public function execute(Observer $observer)
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```
public function execute(Observer $observer)
{
    $items = $observer->getEvent()->getShipment()->getAllItems();
    if($items)
    {
        foreach ($items as $_item) {
            $product_id = $_item->getProductId();
            if(!$this->_isAvailableInWarehouse($product_id))
            {
                $message = $_item->getName().' is not available in warehouse';
                throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(__($message));
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}

protected function _isAvailableInWarehouse($product_id)
{
    // your custom condition code here.
    return false;
}
```